# Rounding a Java BigDecimal to the nearest interval

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal, intervals

I have a BigDecimal calculation result which I need to round to the nearest specified interval (in this case it's the financial market tick size).

e.g. Price [Tick Size] -> Rounded Price

```
100.1 [0.25] -> 100
100.2 [0.25] -> 100.25
100.1 [0.125] -> 100.125
100.2 [0.125] -> 100.25
```

Thanks.

Update: schnaader's solution, translated into Java/BigDecimal terms:

```
price = price.divide(tick).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).multiply(tick)
```

Comment: For searchability, this technique can be used to round a percentage value to some arbitrary fraction of a basis point.

Comment: the `divide()` function takes the scale as arguments as well: `divide(tick, 0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could normalize tick size and then use the usual rounding methods:

```
100.1 [0.25] -> * (1/0.25) -> 400.4 [1]  -> round -> 400 -> / (1/0.25) -> 100
100.2 [0.25] -> * (1/0.25) -> 400.8 [1] -> round -> 401 -> / (1/0.25) -> 100.25
```

So it should be:

```
Price = Round(Price / Tick) * Tick;
```

Also note that you seem to have to set the correct rounding mode for BigDecimals. See [BigDecimal Docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_CEILING) for example. So you should be sure to set this correct and write some tests to check the correctness of your code.

Comment: Looks good thanks! In Java/BigDecimal terms, this translates into the rather ugly: price.divide(tick).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).multiply(tick)

Answer (score 2):

This is more related to **"Rounding a stock price to it's nearest tick size"**.

Answer provided by schnaader is correct, however there are a few things missing.

- First, you must check whether stock price needs rounding. Unnecessary rounding messes up the fractional part.
- Then you also need to handle `ArithmeticException` that might come during `BigDecimal` divide function

Here's my solution. It would take a lot of time to explain it. I'd recommend to try it with some samples to get a feel. Look for the function **`roundTick()`**.

```
import static java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * Utility class for stock price related operations.
 */
public final class PriceFormatter {

    public static final float DELTA = 0.0001f;

    private PriceFormatter() {
    }

    /**
     * Rounds the price to the nearest tick size.
     *
     * @param price    price
     * @param tickSize tick size
     * @return price rounded to the nearest tick size
     */
    public static final float roundTick(final float price, final float tickSize) {
        if (tickSize < DELTA) {
            return price;
        }

        if (!isRoundingNeeded(price, tickSize)) {
            return price;
        }

        final BigDecimal p = new BigDecimal(price);
        final BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(tickSize);

        final BigDecimal roundedPrice = p.divide(t, 0, HALF_UP).multiply(t);

        return roundedPrice.floatValue();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether price needs rounding to the nearest tick size.
     *
     * @param price    price
     * @param tickSize tick size
     * @return true, if rounding is needed; false otherwise
     */
    public static final boolean isRoundingNeeded(final float price, final float tickSize) {
        final int mult = calculateTickMultiplier(tickSize);
        final int mod = (int) (tickSize * mult);
        final float reminder = (((price * mult) % mult) % mod);
        final boolean needsRounding = reminder > DELTA;
        return needsRounding;
    }

    public static final int calculateTickMultiplier(final float tickSize) {
        int result = 1;
        while (((tickSize * result) < 1) || (((tickSize * result) - (int) (tickSize * result)) > DELTA)) {
            result *= 10;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p= p - p % t + ((p % t < t / 2) ? 0.0 : t);
```

//where p= price  and  t= tick increment